# NEXT JS: Build exportPathMap for a dynamic page Route

Tags: next.js

I wanted to build a static export for my NEXT project that looks like following:

```
- pages
---- index.tsx
---- [pageRoute].tsx
```

Now I want to statically generate routeId for `home` page that I have handled as shown below:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import React from 'react';
import { PAGE_ROUTES } from '../constants/config';
import Home from './Home/Home';

type Props = {};

export default function Base({}: Props) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const route = router.query.pageRoute as string;
  let RenderComponent = <div>404: Page Not Found</div>;
  switch (route) {
    case PAGE_ROUTES.HOME: {
      RenderComponent = <Home />;
      break;
    }

    default: {
    }
  }
  return (
    <div className='flex flex-col items-center max-w-sm mx-auto'>
      {RenderComponent}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am not sure what do I specify in `exportPathMaps` in `next.config.js` in order to create static export of `home` page:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  exportPathMap: async function (
    defaultPathMap,
    { dev, dir, outDir, distDir, buildId }
  ) {
    return {
      '/': { page: '/' },
      // how do I add configuration for '/home': {page: '/[pageRoute]',query:{pageRoute:'home'}}
      
    };
  },
};
```

when I do this:

```
      '/home': { page: '/[pageRoute]', query: { pageRoute: 'home' } },
```

It throws error saying:
`Error: you provided query values for /home which is an auto-exported page. These can not be applied since the page can no longer be re-rendered on the server. To disable auto-export for this page add`getInitia
lProps

Comment: You shouldn't use `exportPathMaps` for that. You should use [`getStaticPaths`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-paths)/[`getStaticProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-props) when statically pre-rendering dynamic routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to statically pre-render dynamic paths, you should return them from `getStaticPaths`:

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import React from 'react';
import { PAGE_ROUTES } from '../constants/config';
import Home from './Home/Home';

import type { GetStaticPaths } from 'next'

export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths = async () => {
  const paths = Object.values(PAGE_ROUTES)
    .map(route => [{ params: { pageRoute: route } }])

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false, // meaning any path not returned by `getStaticPaths` will result in a 404 page
  }
}

type Props = {};

export default function Base({}: Props) {
  return (
    <div className='flex flex-col items-center max-w-sm mx-auto'>
      <Home />
    </div>
  );
}
```

And, as @juliomalves said, in that case you don't need `exportPathMap` in `next.config.js`.

For custom 404 page create 404.tsx in /pages

- More about `getStaticPaths` - https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-paths
- `fallback: false` - https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-paths#fallback-false