# Exportpathmap in next.config.js set dynamic routes in NextJS

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am trying to set dynamic routes by using Exportpathmap() in nex.config.js. Static routes is working fine as I want but when I am trying to apply dynamically, the dynamic URL is not working and redirected me to main URL.

Please help me do fix this issue.
Thansk in advance.

Here is my next.config.js

```
return{
    reactStrictMode: true,
    env: env,
    trailingSlash : true,
    eslint: {
        ignoreDuringBuilds: true,
    },
    swcMinify: true,
    images: {
        domains: ['cdn.pixabay.com', 'pixabay.com', 'cdn.landrrapp.io'],
        loader: 'akamai',
        path: '',
    },
    exportPathMap: async function (
        defaultPathMap,
        { dev, dir, outDir, distDir, buildId }
      ) {
        return {
          '/404': { page: '/404' },
          '/forgot-password': { page: '/forgot-password' },
          '/login': { page: '/login' },
          '/editor/[id]': { page: '/editor/[id]' },
        }
      },
}
```

I am facing issue with this one '/editor/[id]': { page: '/editor/[id]' },

[NEXT JS: Build exportPathMap for a dynamic page Route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72574150/next-js-build-exportpathmap-for-a-dynamic-page-route)
Above was lokks fine but I am unable to understand "

```
import { PAGE_ROUTES } from '../constants/config';
```

" this file data.

Comment: Your usage of `exportPathMap` is pointless in this case because you're not changing the route mapping at all. Can you show us the code for the dynamic route `/editor/[id]`?

Answer (score -1):

use this

```
    '/editor/Some Page Name': { page: '/editor/[id]' },
    '/editor/Some Page Name 2': { page: '/editor/[id]' },
    .
    .
    .
```